# When using the Grid-view(on devexpress -visual c#), how do I get the values of four fields of a record when I click on that record/row?

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I want to get the values of four fields of a record and later use them in an sql statement. How can I get those 4 values when I click a row/record in gridview and have each value stored in their own declared variables?

The four field names are course_abbreviation, course_name, month_of_admission and year_of_admission.

```
public LecturerForm(string lecturer_firstname, string lecturer_lastname, string lecturer_id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string lecturer = lecturer_firstname + " " + lecturer_lastname;
        lblname.Text = lecturer;
        string lecID = lecturer_id;
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection cnn;
        connetionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated security=SSPI;database=jms";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select unit_code, unit_name, course_abbreviation, course_name, group_name from units_allocation where national_id='" + lecID + "' ", connetionString);
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        DataTable dt4 = new System.Data.DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt4);
        gridControl1.DataSource = dt4;

        gridView1.Columns[0].Caption = "Unit Code";
        gridView1.Columns[1].Caption = "Unit Name";
        gridView1.Columns[2].Caption = "Course Abbr.";
        gridView1.Columns[3].Caption = "Course Name";
        gridView1.Columns[4].Caption = "Group";
    }

private void gridView1_RowClick(object sender, RowClickEventArgs e)
    {

        //code to get values of four fields and store in four variables...(i.e from the question)
    }
```

Comment: What your platfrom (WinForms, WPF, etc.)? How do you bind the Grid? Provide code to illustrate what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [GridView.RowClick](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowClicktopic) event there is the e.RowHandle argument which you can use to identify a clicked row. Then, use the [GridView.GetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetRowCellValuetopic) method to get a cell value of that row.

```
object val1;
object val2;
object val3;
object val4;
private void gridView1_RowClick(object sender, RowClickEventArgs e) {
    int rowHandle = e.RowHandle;
    val1 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView1.Columns[0]);
    val2 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView1.Columns[1]);
    val3 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView1.Columns[2]);
    val4 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView1.Columns[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems that occur when columns are dragged into different positions it is usually better to reference by name.

```
object val1;
object val2;
object val3;
object val4;
private void gridView1_RowClick(object sender, RowClickEventArgs e) {
    int rowHandle = e.RowHandle;
    val1 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "course_abbreviation");
    val2 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "course_name");
    val3 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "month_of_admission");
    val4 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "year_of_admission");
}
```